# fno-automatic with PURE Functions

Tags: fortran

I use an older code written in Fortran. The makefile has the compiler option "-fno-automatic", which assigns the SAVE statement to all variables. The problem is, that it also assigns the SAVE statement to variables inside a PURE Function. Newer compilers (including mine) will give out an error, if the SAVE Statement is assign to a variable in a PURE function. The error reads:"Error: SAVE attribute at (1) cannot be specified in a PURE procedure".
I googled for some answers and the only thing I found is to explicitely write "automatic" when defining variables (e.g. integer, automatic :: i), and using the flag -fdec-static in the makefile. This works and gets rid of the error. The problem is that the program I use, consists of a lot of these PURE functions, and it would be a bit too much to change all of them. Is there another way to instruct Fortran to NOT use the SAVE statement inside a PURE function, even when the flag (fno-automatic) is used?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: "older code" is contradictory with the use of pure functions...

Answer (score 0):

The `automatic` keyword is completely nonstandard. That's why it would require the `-fdec` flag that enables various nonstandard stuff. I highly suggest to keep your code standard conforming or at least as little non-standard as practically possible and avoid this attribute completely.

Think why you need the `pure` attribute in the first place. If you actually need `elemental` and the `pure` is only added for you implicitly, you can make those functions `impure elemental`, then they do not have to be pure.

If you need to pass them somewhere where `pure` is explicitly used in the declaration of a calling procedure, think twice whether the calling procedure really has to be pure. Perhaps just remove the `pure` attribute where it is not actually possible to fulfill for the procedures being called.

If you only need the `save` attribute in a limited number of procedures, just append it manually and ditch the `-fno-automatic`.

Also, when using these compiler flags, try to use them for as few source file compilation as possible. Really limit their use only where really necessary. Do not just put them into some `FFLAGS` variable for every file that is compiled.

Comment: One other possibility is to add a blank `SAVE` statement to all non-pure subprograms.  This would yield standard conforming code and so should be supported by all compilers, and does not require command line options.

Comment: @steve: even further, the `SAVE` statements should be added only to the legacy code that was relying on this behavior. The use of `SAVE` should be discouraged in new codes, unless really necessary.

Comment: @PierU, I agree 100% with your additional recommendation.  OP should look at each subprogram to determine if `SAVE` is needed; as it can be a performance for code where it is unnecessary.

Comment: @PierU Yes, that is the sort of things I was trying to imply in my fourth paragraph.